# Add a new column based on the presence of a value in in R

Tags: r

I have this df :

```
Plot <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,9,10)
Grp1 <- c("EPB", "SAB", "EPB", "ESS","SAB","SAB", "EPB","SAB", "SAB", "SAB", "SAB","EPB", "SAB","SAB")
df1 <- cbind(Plot, Grp1)
```

and I would like to create another column based on the presence of "EPB" in the plot of the column with the same name.
The final df would look like this :

```
Plot <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,9,10)
Grp1 <- c("EPB", "SAB", "EPB", "ESS","SAB","SAB", "EPB","SAB", "SAB", "SAB", "SAB","EPB", "SAB","SAB")
PEPB <- c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0)
df2 <- df1 <- cbind(Plot, Grp1,PEPB)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can try this. First `group_by` each `Plot`, and then `mutate` to create your new `PEPB` column. You can include `ifelse` logic, such that if `any` of the `Grp1` values within a common `Plot` is equal to `EPB` then set indicator to 1, otherwise use 0.

If your `df1` is indeed a data.frame, no need for `as.data.frame` in your pipe. This was added based on your posted data above.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  group_by(Plot) %>%
  mutate(PEPB = ifelse(any(Grp1 == "EPB"), 1, 0))
```

**Output**

```
   Plot  Grp1   PEPB
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 1     EPB       1
 2 1     SAB       1
 3 2     EPB       1
 4 2     ESS       1
 5 3     SAB       0
 6 4     SAB       0
 7 5     EPB       1
 8 5     SAB       1
 9 6     SAB       0
10 7     SAB       0
11 8     SAB       1
12 8     EPB       1
13 9     SAB       0
14 10    SAB       0
```

Comment: It worked ! I saw the ```ifelse``` function a lot but I never really understood how to use it. Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

ifelse is a really useful command

```
Plot <- c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,9,10)
Grp1 <- c("EPB", "SAB", "EPB", "ESS","SAB","SAB", "EPB","SAB", "SAB", "SAB", "SAB","EPB", "SAB","SAB")
df1 <- cbind(Plot, Grp1)
df1<- as.data.frame(df1)
df1$PEPB <- ifelse(df1$Grp1 == "EPB",1,0)
```